# How to implement Custom ScrollView Like listview?

Tags: android, scrollview, android-custom-view

I want to add my Listview in another scroll view but when i add it in scrollview in xml it show only one item.so i want to create custom scroll view so i can put it in another scrollview.

Comment: would you mind to elaborate why you want to do this? putting a listview into scrollview is not recommended, have you considered using expandablelistview or list header/footer?

Comment: i found half solution from this link androidhub4you.com/2012/12/… but when i use this then setOnScrollListener not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Things to take into account:

- `ScrollView` can only have a single child. If you want to add more of them you have to put them inside another `ViewGroup`, then add it to the `ScrollView`.
- `ListView` handles its own scrolling, you should never put it inside another `ScrollView`.

If what you need is to have a certain number elements, a list of items included, scroll together as a single entity, you have two options:

- Do not use a `ListView`, but a vertical `LinearLayout`. It will work, but with this all your rows will be created at once and won't be recycled while scrolling, so you should only do this if you can be sure your list will have a limited number of items.
- A better option is to use a `ListView` as your main `ViewGroup` and add to it every other element you need in the scroll as headers or footers.